# How to display YouTube videos without exiting the application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube

I have a button in my iPhone app which launches the iPhone YouTube player and plays a video. The code I use is this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx"]];
```

It works fine, but when I stop the video (or it ends) the context does not come back to the app from which I run YouTube. It just remains in YouTube or, if I force its closure, turns to the iPhone menu.

Is there any way to come back to the executing app?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Display YouTube Videos Without Exiting Your Application](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html)